# Subsetting with for function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

Trying to use a function to get the means of multiple different subsets of columns and add them as new columns. DMcomponents defines a character vector. Each entry in this vector is defined by its own character vector with column names.

```
for (i in DMcomponents){
  DMData["i"] <- rowMeans(DMData[c(i)])
}
```

In my mind, this should work, but I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(DMData, c(i)) : undefined columns selected
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with how the vector is "pasted" into the subset argument? Thanks

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
a <- c(4, 4, 4)
b <- c(6, 6, 6)
c <- c(8, 8, 8)
d <- c(10, 10, 10)

abcd <- data.frame(id, a, b, c, d)


DMcomponents <- c("ab", "cd")

ab <- c("a", "b")
cd <- c("c", "d")

ab <- c(5, 5, 5)
cd <- c(9, 9, 9)
```

desired result:

```
abcd_end <- data.frame(id, a, b, c, d, ab, cd)
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could show us some samples of `DMcomponents` and `DMData` and potentially the package you're using to create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to quote

```
lst1 <- mget(DMcomponents)

 for (nm in names(lst1)){
    abcd[nm] <- rowMeans(abcd[lst1[[nm]]])
  }

abcd
#  id a b c  d ab cd
#1  1 4 6 8 10  5  9
#2  2 4 6 8 10  5  9
#3  3 4 6 8 10  5  9
```

#### data

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
a <- c(4, 4, 4)
b <- c(6, 6, 6)
c <- c(8, 8, 8)
d <- c(10, 10, 10)

abcd <- data.frame(id, a, b, c, d)
DMcomponents <- c("ab", "cd")
ab <- c("a", "b")
cd <- c("c", "d")
```

Comment: I want to create a new column with the name of each entry in DMcomponents, with the data being the mean of columns specified by a seperate vector for each entry in DMcomponents. (ex. DMcomponents = c("ab", "cd"), ab = c("a", "b"), dc = c("c", "d"), where the result is columns ab and dc with the averages of a,b and c,d, respectively)

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 if you want to create means of column use `colMeans` or `mean(DMData[[i]])`

Comment: mean of rows in specified columns*

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 is this a `list` orr vector (DMComponents)

Comment: not sure... thought this was called a vector, defined as DMcomponents <- c("ab", "cd")

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 can you please update wth a small reproducible example as it is not clearr

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 If `DMcomponents <- c("ab", "cd")`, you want the first element to ssplit into 'a', 'b'.  supppose if it is 'abc' or 'a_b', then what would be the case

Comment: see revised question

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 i assume that you have already created `ab <- c("a", "b")`

Comment: I have, but some of the "sub-vectors" are only one character string long, and I get this error with the mget function Error: value for ‘(one value char)’ not found

Comment: Found the problem! One vector was misnamed!